# Find corresponding ID in objects

Tags: reactjs

I am trying to find the updated value in another array. The select has the label from one array, but if I update this food item in another array it does not show the updated value. It does show the updated label in the select drop down though, but not the label.

I have the following code:

```
{item && item.Foods && item.Foods.length > 0 && item.Foods.map((xxx, index) => {
          return (
            <React.Fragment key={`${xxx}~${index}`}>
              <Select
              isSearchable={ true }
               ref={myRef} 
               menuPortalTarget={document.body} 
               placeholder="Select Foods" 
               name="Foods" 
               value={getCategoryLabel(xxx)}
               options={options} 
               >
```

and getCategoryLabel:

```
const getCategoryLabel = (xxx) => {
  if (xxx.id) {
    const foundCategory = options?.find((element) => element.id == xxx.id)
    if (foundCategory) {
      return foundCategory.label
    }
  }
  return xxx.label ?? ""
}
```

The xxx object:

```
{
    "Quantity": "2.00",
    "id": "T2ajRjW7uahiFm2NLspG",
    "label": "BaconY",
    "value": "BaconY",
    "Weight": "0.400",
    "Food": ""
}
```

The options object:

```
[
    
    {
        "value": "Apples",
        "label": "Apples",
        "Weight": 0.075,
        "id": "76289e30-15da-11ec-b278-b1ac8c1941a3"
    },
    {
        "value": "BaconX",
        "label": "BaconX",
        "Weight": "0.400",
        "id": "T2ajRjW7uahiFm2NLspG"
    }
]
```

As you can see the correct label is BaconX - but it is showing as BaconY

Comment: your `BaconY` and `BaconX` ids are the same `T2ajRjW7uahiFm2NLspG` so if your doing a search by ID than it should be a unique ID

Comment: also can improve the readability of this part `item && item.Foods && item.Foods.length > 0` by doing this instead: `!!item?.Foods?.length` - same thing but more readable

Comment: So how do I match the id to the correct name which is BaconX so it displays this instead of the previously written value of BaconY?

Comment: if you want to overwrite `BaconY` with `BaconX` than before adding `baconx` remove the `baconY` and add `baconx`. if you want to keep both values - make sure the `id` property is unique between objects. or you could do a search by ID and name.